# How to achieve this type of collection view grid

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I just want to achieve a collectionview grid like below image, but I am unable to do the same.
Can anyone help me out ?

Here is my code:-

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
              layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    if (indexPath.row%2==0) {
        return CGSizeMake(self.collectionView.frame.size.width, 80);
    }
    return CGSizeMake(self.collectionView.frame.size.width/2, 80);


}
```

// vertical space between cell

```
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
               layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout
minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
   return 5.0;
}

- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *) collectionView
                    layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *) collectionViewLayout
    insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger) section {

    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0); // top, left, bottom, right
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *) collectionView
               layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *) collectionViewLayout
minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger) section {
     return 0;
}
```

But the outcome of this code is cells in green background[image]

[image: Required]

Comment: you can achieve this by tableview also by taking two different Cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try this. Change your `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` function with my one.

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
          layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row%3==0) {
        return CGSizeMake(self.collectionView.frame.size.width, 80);
    }
    CGFloat minSpace = 10; //Set this minSpace for space that you want between two cell
    return CGSizeMake((self.collectionView.frame.size.width - minSpace)/2, 80);
}
```

Also change your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` if condition with this if condition to return two different cell. If you have.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Your target cell index order order are **0**, 1,2 , **3**, 4,5 **6**, 7,8 **9**,......    Your order for identification is 0,3,6,9...  code for size for item at indexpath should be

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    NSUInteger pos = indexPath.row;
    if(pos%3==0)
    {
        return CGSizeMake(dynamicCollection.frame.size.width-10, 80);

    }
    else
    {
       return CGSizeMake(dynamicCollection.frame.size.width/2-10, 80);
    }

}
```

In your story board provide inset for sections 5,5,5,5 . Select the collectionview and in scale attribute.

[image]

Comment: I found where I was doing wrong. Anyways thanks. Take +1 for this.